possible to share a csv file from google drive without key (just url like http://www.example.com/file.csv)
I'd like to share a csv via google drive (or other similar service) such that the file is returned via http (ie progromatically and not with some UI representation) such as http://drive.google.com/my-user-id/file.csv. This used to work with Dropbox but I think they removed this feature.
When I share via "share with everybody", I get this dialog box

but this shares a link that goes to their docs not to just the csv file. I can use publish to web but this requires a key which I'm very hesitant to use for accessing.

That's just how it is. Officially users are supposed to click Download from inside that preview screen.
But unofficially, there's a secret link that gives a pure download link - https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=[ID] where [ID] needs to be replaced with the file's ID, which can be seen in the preview link (the [ID] in https://drive.google.com/file/d/[ID]/view).
You can search online for direct google drive download link for forms or extensions that automatically give you this link if you give them your preview link.
Note Google caps this secret link to X downloads a day, etc.


ugh... the capping is a bit of a deal breaker. I tried manipulating the url to something like xFV3ZU/view\?output\=csv as what we really want is just the csv part but no dice
